# USB detected slowly and does not auto mount in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, xubuntu, automount

I have recently installed Xubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Studio 1558 laptop, and I find that by USB is now taking a long time to be detected and does not get auto mounted by the file manager. It used to work fine with the 17.XX version of Xubuntu.

I find that right after plugging in the USB, dmesg shows that it has detected the USB, but the entry in /dev is created only after some time. Even after the entry gets created (/dev/sdb), it is not auto mounted. I can manually mount the USB and it is accessible after that.

I have checked dconf editor for auto mount options and they look fine. The drive does not show up in Disks utility either.

Following are my observations:

dmesg and other command output (right after plugging in the USB)

```
privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  14.7G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 104.8G  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part
└─sda6   8:6    0 170.7G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for privat:
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x06d985af

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63     80324     80262  39.2M de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2           80325  30800324  30720000  14.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        30800325 250624148 219823824 104.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       250626046 625141759 374515714 178.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       608653312 625141759  16488448   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       250626048 608653311 358027264 170.7G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M  1.4M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda6       168G   15G  145G  10% /
tmpfs           3.9G   23M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           784M   16K  784M   1% /run/user/1000

dmesg snippet:

[  445.202900] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  445.323808] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  445.323811] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  445.323812] usb 2-1.3: Product: Cruzer Blade
[  445.323813] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  445.323815] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 4C530000210213115415

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6416 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lshw

        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f0b06000-f0b063ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.0.0-31-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.00
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: USB hub
                      product: BCM2046B1
                      vendor: Broadcom
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@1:1.1
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=hub maxpower=94mA slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb:0
                         description: Keyboard
                         product: Integrated Keyboard
                         vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@1:1.1.1
                         version: 1.00
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=2mA speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                         description: Mouse
                         product: Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
                         vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
                         physical id: 2
                         bus info: usb@1:1.1.2
                         version: 1.00
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: maxpower=2mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2M
                      vendor: M092S-H02-0525-SC48Q
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      version: a1.15
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=168mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

After some time, I see the /dev/sdb entry. Output of commands after this:

```
dmesg snippet:

[  445.202900] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  445.323808] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  445.323811] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  445.323812] usb 2-1.3: Product: Cruzer Blade
[  445.323813] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  445.323815] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 4C530000210213115415
[  815.370890] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  815.371165] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[  815.371305] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  815.412954] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  816.382630] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  816.383044] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  816.384110] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 122585088 512-byte logical blocks: (62.8 GB/58.5 GiB)
[  816.385620] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  816.385623] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  816.386606] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  816.401129]  sdb: sdb1
[  816.404620] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  14.7G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 104.8G  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part
└─sda6   8:6    0 170.7G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  58.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   1  58.5G  0 part
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x06d985af

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63     80324     80262  39.2M de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2           80325  30800324  30720000  14.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        30800325 250624148 219823824 104.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       250626046 625141759 374515714 178.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       608653312 625141759  16488448   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       250626048 608653311 358027264 170.7G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 58.5 GiB, 62763565056 bytes, 122585088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          32 122585087 122585056 58.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6416 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The drive is not auto mounted even after this. Manual mount works fine:

```
privat@privat-Studio-1558:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

I am wondering why the /dev entry might be getting installed slowly, and auto mount does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, What is the model of USB Disk (SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade). Is it a USB3 device? If it is so, try another device, USB2.  If it works fine, check BIOS version and if there any new firmware/driver update for BIOS, Chipset and USB2 controller.

Comment: And search with `journalctl | grep uas` after error with this modul. Show the entries if present by edding your question please.